# date time picker bootstrap

Tags: date, datetime

I'm developing an application where i have to create a date time picker for users,but problem is that i'm using bootstrap date time picker from here:-
[for date time picker](https://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) which is giving me another bydefault time.its 12 hours ahead form my local time so what i should do for this.
if u have any idea to do on another method please suggest me.

and another question is my i'm trying to converting user's time date into UTC time using this:-`$datetime1=gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($datetime));`
 and its not converting correct UTC time.please suggest me what i have to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the locale value for datetimepicker on the link you provided is `language: 'pt-BR'`. Change it to 'en-US' or any other valid value <strike>to achieve correct timezone for datetime</strike>.

Comment: its same 12 hours ahead even I changed it to "en-IN" ,i'm stuck what i have to do.

Comment: actually i'm searching all  datetime picker on every site but all site defines same time there,i cant understand how to change this.

Comment: do u have any other method for this??

Comment: can any body tell me how to convert local date time to UTC timestamp in php.

Comment: hey rt2800..you were correct..the problem is in my settings only..thank you..:-)